# How to write multiple commands in a for loop on Mac terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm trying to run multiple commands inside a for loop on Mac terminal. I separated the commands using the semicolon ";". The first command ran as I expected. However, I expected the second command `head -n 1 $filename` to print the first line of every file in the list but it only printed that of the last file. Why is that?

I'm also assuming that shell would run the first and second commands together for an item in the list before it jump to the next item and run two commands for that again. It looks like it's not the case. How do I do that?

```
(base) xyz@zzz-MBP creatures % ls
basilisk.dat        original-basilisk.dat   original-unicorn.dat
minotaur.dat        original-minotaur.dat   unicorn.dat

(base) xyz@zzz-MBP creatures % for filename in *.dat
for> echo $filename;head -n 1 $filename
basilisk.dat
minotaur.dat
original-basilisk.dat
original-minotaur.dat
original-unicorn.dat
unicorn.dat
COMMON NAME: unicorn
```

I thought it might be caused by the wrong formatting as I didn't put do and done. I then did that but it showed another error.

```
(base) xyz@zzz-MBP creatures % for filename in *dat                
for> do echo $filename; do head -n 1 $filename; done
zsh: parse error near `do'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a formatting issue.

Solved by doing this:

```
(base) xyz@zzz-MBP creatures % for filename in *dat                
for> do echo $filename; head -n 1 $filename; done
```